# how separate functions and call them php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony, controllers

I have one project in symfony 2... and I have this issue.

I have this file **src/ApiV1Bundle/Controller/TeamsController.php** witch have this content:

```
 <?php

namespace ApiV1Bundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Teams;
use ApiV1Bundle\Collection\TeamsCollection;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;

Class TeamsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all Teams entities.
     *
     */
    public function getTeamsAction()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $teams = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Teams')->findBy(['active' => 1]);
        $resource = [];

        foreach ($teams as $team) {
            array_push($resource, $this->displayTeam($team));
        }

        $response = new Response(json_encode($resource));

        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }

    function displayTeam(Teams $team)
    {
        $slug = new Slugify();

        $resource['id'] = $team->getId();
        $resource['name'] = $team->getName();
        $resource['slug'] = $slug->slugify($team->getName());
        $resource['league'] = $slug->slugify($team->getLeagueId());
        $resource['shield'] = $slug->slugify($team->getMultimediaId());

        return $resource;
    }

}
```

And this works perfectly... but i need separate the auxiliary functions, to the main code... in one file like this.

This is the route: **src/ApiV1Bundle/Collection/TeamCollection.php**, with this content:

```
<?php

namespace ApiV1Bundle\Collection;

use AppBundle\Entity\Teams; use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;

Class TeamsCollection {

    function displayTeam(Teams $team)
    {
        $slug = new Slugify();

        $resource['id'] = $team->getId();
        $resource['name'] = $team->getName();
        $resource['slug'] = $slug->slugify($team->getName());
        $resource['league'] = $slug->slugify($team->getLeagueId());
        $resource['shield'] = $slug->slugify($team->getMultimediaId());

        return $resource;
    }
 }
```

This for keep the controller file more clean, But I would not know what to call this new file in my driver, or if I'm creating good, or if something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my suggestion:

```
use ApiV1Bundle\Collection\TeamsCollection;

public function getTeamsAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $teams = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Teams')->findBy(['active' => 1]);
    $resource = $team->map(function($team) {
        return TeamsCollection::displayTeam($team)
    };

    $response = new JsonResponse($resource);

    return $response;
}
```

In this case, you have to make `displayTeam` a static function. Alternatively, you can do this:

```
$teamcollection = new TeamCollection();
return $teamcollection->displayTeam($team);
```

As a bonus, I gave two other suggestions:

- Use JsonResponse instead of Response. In that case you don't have to set a `Content-Type`. Setting StatusCode to 200 is not necessary: it's the default status.
- Use `ArrayCollection::map`. It's a great function, but (unfortunately) it isn't very popular.